# Chrome emulating touch area detection is not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I discovered that the chrome mobile emulator touch detection is not accurate.

The click event is also fired even If I click outside the target DOM.

According to my demo, the click event is fired unexpectedly when clicking between the red border and the green border.

I know it cannot be repeated in real mobile devices, but it is pretty confusing for the development

Any reason why?

---

Demo:

Only View: https://kdlmxn.csb.app/

Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-monad-kdlmxn?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

Comment: At a guess, Chrome dev tools are garbage?